# Write a program annual income of the emp and find the income tax

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

Write a program annual income of the emp and find the income tax of the employee table.

Output should be first_name,salary,ann_sal and tax.

- i) If the annsal > 60000 then tax is 10% of income
- ii) If the annsal > 100000 then tax is Rs 800+16% of income
- iii) If the annsal > 140000 then tax is Rs 2500+25% of income

Sample Data

```
FIRST_NAME              SALARY

Steven                    24000
Neena                     17000
Lex                       17000
Alexander                  9000
Bruce                      6000
David                      4800
Valli                      4800
Diana                      4200
Nancy                     12008
Daniel                     9000
```

Here is my program:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR income
    IS
        SELECT first_name,
            salary,
            salary*12 ann_sal
        FROM EMPLOYEES;
    z income%rowtype;
    ann_sal NUMBER(8,2);
    tax     NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
    OPEN income;
    LOOP
        FETCH income
        INTO z;
        EXIT
    WHEN income%notfound;
        IF ann_sal>60000 THEN
            tax  :=ann_sal*10/100;
        elsif ann_sal>100000 THEN
            tax     :=800+ann_sal*16/100;
        elsif ann_sal>140000 THEN
            tax     :=2500+ann_sal*25/100;
        ELSE
            tax:='';
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(z.first_name || '  ' || z.salary || ' ' ||z.ann_sal|| '  ' || z.tax);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE income;
END;
```

this is it.

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward. Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: I couldn't show the tax column in output.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Instead of `z.tax` in `dbms_output.put_line`, just use `tax` as its not part of the cursor.

Comment: But tax column is not showing after use only tax @Nitish

Comment: Use `z.ann_sal` in the ifs.

Comment: The code is messed up . ann_sal is initialized but never  assigned any value.

Comment: i know it's messed up , can anyone give me the right query of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There You go. I have re-written the code. Let me know if the output is as expected.

```
   DECLARE
        CURSOR income IS
          SELECT first_name,
                 salary,
                 salary * 12 ann_sal
          FROM   employees;
        z       income%ROWTYPE;
        tax     NUMBER(8, 2);
    BEGIN
        OPEN income;

        LOOP
            FETCH income INTO z;

            exit WHEN income%NOTFOUND;

            IF z.ann_sal > 60000 THEN
              tax := z.ann_sal * 10 / 100;
            ELSIF z.ann_sal > 100000 THEN
              tax := 800 + z.ann_sal * 16 / 100;
            ELSIF z.ann_sal > 140000 THEN
              tax := 2500 + z.ann_sal * 25 / 100;
            ELSE
              tax := '';
            END IF;

            dbms_output.Put_line(z.first_name
                                 || '  '
                                 || z.salary
                                 || ' '
                                 ||z.ann_sal
                                 || '  '
                                 || tax);
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE income;
    END;
```

Comment: If you're cleaning it up, you might get rid of the open-fetch-exit-close construction and replace it with a simpler cursor FOR loop. That's if the whole looping business is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL for this.

```
select first_name
     , salary
     , salary * 12 ann_sal
     , case
           when salary * 12 > 140000 then 2500 + (salary * 12 * 25) / 100
           when salary * 12 > 100000 then  800 + (salary * 12 * 16) / 100
           when salary * 12 >  60000 then salary * 12 * 10 / 100
           else 0
       end as tax
from   employees;
```

Note that any salary over 100000 is also over 60000, so in your original code you never reach the `> 100000` or `> 140000` conditions. I have rearranged the conditions to check downwards from the largest salary.

If for some reason you really need it in a PL/SQL loop, there is no need to declare anything:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select first_name
             , salary
             , salary * 12 ann_sal
             , case
                   when salary * 12 > 140000 then 2500 + (salary * 12 * 25) / 100
                   when salary * 12 > 100000 then  800 + (salary * 12 * 16) / 100
                   when salary * 12 >  60000 then salary * 12 * 10 / 100
                   else 0
               end as tax
        from   employees
        order by first_name
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(rpad(r.first_name,15) || lpad(r.salary,9) || lpad(r.ann_sal,9) || lpad(r.tax,9));
    end loop;
end;
```